# bash seems to ignore BASH_ENV when accessed through a symlink

Tags: bash, symlink, non-interactive

I'm working in a UNIX environment where `/bin` has been set up like this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 617144 Nov 19  2009 bash
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Nov 23  2010 sh -> bash
```

In my environment I have set `$BASH_ENV` to point to my local .bashrc:

```
env | grep BASH
BASH_ENV=/home/users/atomicpirate/.bashrc
```

In addition, .bashrc has as its first line `echo BASHRC READ`.

I would expect /bin/sh and /bin/bash to behave exactly the same with this setup...but they don't:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo $BASH_ENV'
BASHRC READ
/home/users/atomicpirate/.bashrc

/bin/sh -c 'echo $BASH_ENV'
/home/users/atomicpirate/.bashrc
```

In the second case, .bashrc is NOT read.  Any idea why this would be the case?  It seems like the symlink is breaking the expected behavior of $BASH_ENV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of
>   historical versions of sh as closely as possible,
>   while conforming  to  the
>   POSIX  standard  as  well.

Note that when run as interactive shell, modern `sh` uses `$ENV` in a manner similar to the way `bash` uses `$BASH_ENV`. This behavior is mimicked by bash as well.

Comment: That's an interesting bit about `$ENV`, I wasn't aware that `sh` had a similar environment variable to `bash`'s `$BASH_ENV`.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking into it a bit further, `sh` only uses `$ENV` for interactive shells whereas bash uses `$BASH_ENV` for both interactive and non-interactive shells.  So, in the case above just using `$ENV` wouldn't have changed the outcome.  Still it's good to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the answer. Note that `sh` behavior changed over time significantly. Here is an excerpt from FreeBSD sh manpage: "Unlike older versions of sh the ENV script is only sourced on invocation of interactive shells. This closes a well-known, and sometimes easily exploitable security hole related to poorly thought out ENV scripts."

Comment: Link to UNIX sh manpage: http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF422/sh.html

Answer (score 3):

When `bash` is invoked as `sh`, it intentionally behaves differently, and disables a number of `bash` extensions.

One of the changes, it appears, is that it no longer reads the file dictated by `$BASH_ENV`.  You could prove that it is nothing to do with a symlink by making the file into a regular file (temporarily) and seeing the same behaviour with a regular file.

Comment: You are right--it has nothing to do with the symlink, it's only to do with the name of the shell when it is invoked.  Wasn't aware of this behavior--thanks!