# Python subprocess.call a bash alias

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

At work there's a script that lists completed tasks. This was written by someone else and is hosted over the network. I have an alias in my .bashrc that calls this script, with its many flags and such, and I wanted to write a python script that would call this alias every few minutes so I can have a shell open with updated stats. However, `subprocess.call("myAlias")` fails. I'm still fairly new to python, and am struggling to figure this out.

```py
from subprocess import call

def callAlias():
    call("myAlias")

callAlias()
```

I plan on adding more too it, but I hit the snag on my first step. :P

I would post more, but there's a lot of sensitive confidential stuff I have to be careful with. Sorry for the vague code, and lack of error output.

Comment: In a case like this, it is probably better to put the script name and all the arguments in a list of strings and use that for your `call`, rather than rely on an alias that may or may not be present.

Comment: Avoiding the use of an alias is the easiest and common solution to this problem. Either inline the alias into your `call()` args, or convert the alias into a script that `call()` can invoke.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**Update:** Thanks for the upvotes for this hack to workaround the problem, I'm glad it's useful. But a much *better* answer is [tripleee's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49209211).

---

If the alias you require is defined in ~/.bashrc, then it won't get run for a few reasons:

1. You must give the `shell` keyword arg:

   ```py
   subprocess.call('command', shell=True)
   ```

   Otherwise your given command is used to find an executable file, rather than passed to a shell, and it is the shell which expands things like aliases and functions.
2. By default, `subprocess.call` and friends use the `/bin/sh` shell. If this is a Bash alias you want to invoke, you'll need to tell subprocess to use bash instead of sh, using the `executable` keyword arg:

   ```py
   subprocess.call('command', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
   ```
3. However, /bin/bash will not source ~/.bashrc unless started as an 'interactive' shell (with `-i`.) Unfortunately, you can't pass `executable='/bin/bash -i'`, as it thinks the whole value is the name of an executable. So if your alias is defined in the user's normal interactive startup, e.g. in .bashrc, then you'll have to invoke the command using this alternative form:

   ```py
   subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', command])
   # i.e. shell=False (the default)
   ```

Comment: good answer. it's [now recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api) (and easier) to use subprocess.run(), rather than subprocess.call()

Comment: How do you translate the above command for `subprocess.run`. I tried ```subprocess.run(['echo', "something"], capture_output=True, shell=True, check=True, env=my_env)```

Comment: I know you decided to put yourself down, and thanks for linking to the informative answer of triplee. But you did answer the question as posed, and even if the 'better' answer is 'don't use an alias', I still found your answer very useful as a learning exercise. Many thanks!

Answer (score 25):

You need to set the `shell` keyword to True:

```
call("myAlias", shell=True)
```

From the [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If `shell` is `True`, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want access to other shell features such as filename wildcards, shell pipes and environment variable expansion.

Aliases are a shell feature (e.g. they are defined and interpreted by the shell).

However, the shell (/bin/sh) is executed non-interactively, so no `.profile` or `.bashrc` files are read and your alias probably is not going to be available.

If you are reluctant to use the full expanded command into your python script, you'll have to use the [`$ENV` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036123) to make the shell read the file with the alias defined in it anyway:

```
call("myAlias", shell=True, env=dict(ENV='/path/to/aliasfile'))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This has be once step close, except now I'm getting the error /bin/sh: myAlias: command not found.
Running the alias exactly as it is in my script works, so it's not a sourcing issue...

Comment: Aliases are only enabled in interactive shells by default.

Comment: FWIW, bash aliases aren't as powerful as bash shell functions.

Answer (score 24):

The recommended solution is to not *use* an alias to define functionality which isn't *exclusively* for interactive use (and even then, shell functions are superior in a number of ways).

Refactor the alias into a standalone script and call it like any other external command.

In more detail, if you have

```bash
alias myalias='for x in foo bar baz; do
    frobnicate "$x"; done'
```

you can improve it so it doesn't pollute your global namespace by turning it into a function

```bash
myalias () {
    local x
    for x in foo bar baz; do
        frobnicate "$x"
    done
}
```

or just save it as  `/usr/local/bin/myalias` and `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/myalias` to make it executable for everyone;

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for x in foo bar baz; do
    frobnicate "$x"
done
```

(This runs in a subprocess so `x` will be gone when the script finishes; so we don't need to make it `local`.)

(Of course, if `frobnicate` is at all competently written, maybe you can simplify to just `frobnicate foo bar baz` as well.)

This is a common FAQ.

Comment: You have been robbed on the voting for this answer. Yours should be the top/accepted answer, instead of my ghastly convoluted hack.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Thanks for the upvote and the comment (-:

Comment: Sometimes you HAVE to use aliases. Like when you want to run some snap installed app from another + many other circumstances...

Comment: @rubmz That doesn't sound at all like you need an alias. In fact, it sounds like yet another situation where an alias would be inferior to a function, shell wrapper, or `PATH` adjustment.

Comment: say you want to programatically start an existing app. That app can be installed anywhere in the os, but it has (and will always have) an alias, a short catchy alias which you want to invoke. Won't that be useful?

Comment: If there is a situation where *only* an alias provides this, perhaps you could link us to a fuller exposition of why that is.

Answer (score 6):

I modified Jonathan's reason #2 slightly to make this work. Make a `/usr/local/bin/interactive_bash` file that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash -i "$@"
```

and `chmod +x` it. Then from Python you can call

```
subprocess.call('my_alias', shell=True, executable='/usr/local/bin/interactive_bash')
```

Comment: Interesting idea, especially for when hacking around on your own machine. Might be tricky if deploying to someone else's machine though.

Comment: Yeah, this probably isn't something I'd feel good about using in production :)