# Python and alias in subprocess

Tags: python, bash, alias

Why does this not work:

```
command = "source InitVariables.sh ; run_simnogui"
r = subprocess.call(command, shell=True,executable='/bin/bash')
```

**Output**

```
/bin/bash: run_simnogui: command not found
```

I use this script everywhere and it works, it defines `run_simnogui` as an alias and it should then be available in the subprocess...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias

Comment: thx for the lin, but non of the already answered version works for me

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the shell receives the following text as a single command line:

```
source InitVariables.sh ; run_simnogui
```

Alias expansion is performed before any of the input is executed, so `run_simnogui` is not yet defined when it needs to be expanded. Once the line is expanded, the shell is only looking for a built-in command named `run_simnogui` or such a command in your path, and so it fails.

The solution, as is almost always the case with aliases, is to use a shell function instead. Define `run_simnogui` as a function in `InitVariables.sh`:

```
run_simnogui () {
    # Put body here
}
```

Now when you call `subprocess.call`, the lookup for `run_simnogui` will succeed because a function by that name is defined by the previous `source` command.