# Python3 Run Alias Bash Commands

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have the following code that works great to run the ls command. I have a bash alias that I use `alias ll='ls -alFGh'` is it possible to get python to run the bash command without python loading my bash_alias file, parsing, and then actually running the full command?

```
import subprocess

command = "ls"  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

#Launch the shell command:
output = process.communicate()

print (output[0])
```

Trying with command = "ll" the output I get is:

```
/bin/sh: ll: command not found
b''
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias

Comment: I don't want to be obnoxious, but why are you using subprocess to list files? Wouldn't `import os` `os.listdir()` achieve what you want?

Comment: Please note alias' are a shell thing, not a bash thing, so, your system has no knowledge of the alias. You can have the command execute through a shell, but that will still result in your alias file being parsed (when the shell loads it will parse it)

Comment: My actual command is piping commands into a docker container, this was just an example to break the problem down

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer your question, but you can of course do `subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-alFGh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)` instead (especially given `shell=True` is generally disuaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  When you run a python process it has no knowledge of a shell alias.  There are simple ways of passing text from parent to child process (other than IPC), the command-line and through environment (i.e. exported) variables.  Bash does not support exporting aliases.

From the `man bash` pages:  *For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.*

Bash *does* support exporting functions, so I suggest you make your alias a simple function instead.  That way it is exported from shell to python to shell.  For example:

In the shell:

```
ll() { ls -l; }
export -f ll
```

In python:

```
import subprocess

command = "ll"  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

output = process.communicate()

print(output[0].decode())    # Required if using Python 3
```

Since you are using the `print()` function I have assumed you are using python 3.  In which case you need the `.decode()`, since a bytes object is returned.

With a bit of hackery it is possible to create and export shell functions from python as well.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is very very helpful