# Executing bash profile aliases from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I am aware that many similar questions have been posted here **but none of them seems to work in my case**. I have a few commands in my bash profile like below

```
export HEADAS=/Users/heasoft/x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
alias heainit=". $HEADAS/headas-init.sh"
. $HEADAS/headas-init.sh

export SAS_DIR=/Users/sas-Darwin-16.7.0-64/xmmsas
alias sas=". $SAS_DIR/setsas.sh"

sit='source ~/.bash_profile'
```

in which I created an alias to run them consecutively: `alias prep1='sit; heainit; sas`. This works just fine when I execute it in the command line. But I want to insert in a python script and run it from there. I am running **Python (v 3.7.4)**. So, as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901022/python3-run-alias-bash-commands), I tried

```
import subprocess

command = "prep1"
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()   
print(output[0].decode())
```

But I get an error saying command not found. I tried to export it in bash profile but got an error stating `-bash: export: prep1: not a function`

I also tried the method suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias), but still nothing. Related to this, I couldn't even run a shell command like below in python

```
epatplot set=evli.FTZ plotfile="pn_filtered_pat.ps" 2>&1 | tee pn_filtered_pat.txt
```

Here is my **Python** script attempt

```
command = "epatplot set=evli.FTZ plotfile="pn_filtered_pat.ps" 2>&1 | tee pn_filtered_pat.txt"
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I know where this syntax error is rising from but don't know how to fix.

I am a beginner in python so I appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: You can create a bash child processes, which reads your alias-commands, but what are you then going to do with this? You can not evern execute them in the very same subprocess (unless  you explicitly turn on alias processing for non-interactive shells), and of course their definition is gone in every other subprocess you are creating later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/98791/1100014

The recommendation is to convert your aliases to bash functions and then export them with `-f` to be available in subshells.

When you call `Popen`, execute `"bash -c <functionname>"`.

As for your last script attempt, you have a conflict in quotation marks.  Replace the outer quotes with single quotes like this:

```
command = 'epatplot set=evli.FTZ plotfile="pn_filtered_pat.ps" 2>&1 | tee pn_filtered_pat.txt'
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: in macOS (Ventura 13.2) bash functions defined without the "function" keyword would cause error: syntax error near unexpected token `('.

A definition with the keyword (cf. https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/) would execute just fine.