# How to open (and keep open) a terminal window using Python to run Appium?

Tags: python, subprocess, appium

I am using python to write an automation script where I would like to start appium programmatically each time it is run.  I am running my scripts using a MAC.  I have tried many things to get appium to run and all I get are errors about file or directory not found and nothing happens.  Here are some details:

- Running 'which appium' using terminal gives me /usr/local/bin/appium
- Looking at /usr/local/bin/appium shows it's an alias (not sure if that's helpful)
- I have tried to run subprocess in various ways in my code with no luck.
- I tried all the suggestions in [Python subprocess.call a bash alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias) and nothing worked.
- I tried using os.('path/to/appium') and no good.
- I created a bash file starting appium located on my desktop which runs great when I manually run it, but comes back with 'line 1: appium: command not found' when I run it.

Apparently when I run python, it can't find appium, but I'm stumped at this point.  I have /usr/local/bin in my .bash_profile in PATH.  Is this not enough?

or should I be trying to start appium a different way?

Thanks for any help!

Error messages I'm getting are:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'appium --port 4725'

Comment: Does your `os.environ['PATH']` have the `/usr/local/bin` path ? 
have you tried giving subprocess the environment of your process. 
eg `subprocess.Popen(command, env=os.environ)`.
What is the error you get can you edit the question to update the errors

Comment: This is what I tried after your suggestion:  os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/local/bin/',      appiumCommand = 'appium --port 4725', subprocess.Popen(appiumCommand, env=os.environ).  I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'appium --port 4725'

Comment: probably best to add to the 'PATH' rather than overwriting it' ? How does your alias look ? and setting the shell=True in subprocess call `subprocess.Popen(command, env=os.environ,shell=True)`. If it is an alias in .basrc you might need to use interactive shell to run the command

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to all of this.  What do you mean if the alias in .basrc?  I installed appium and the alias was automatically created, so I'm not sure about that.  How do I run with interactive shell?  I now add my path to os.environ instead of overwriting and I set shell=True, but still getting the same error.

Comment: subprocess.Popen(''/usr/local/bin/aapium --port 4725", env=os.environ,shell=True) gives you the same error ?
interactive shell `subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', command],shell=False)`

Comment: Do you mind adding the code snippet having the problem to the question ?

Comment: Your second suggestion worked!  appiumCommand = 'appium --port 4725', subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', appiumCommand],shell=False).  Do you know why this works and the others didn't?

Comment: `-i` will launch an interactive shell to run the command. By default your bashrc and profile env is not read, interactive shell reads the startup files and sets up the alias and environment. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html