# running shell command from python

Tags: python, shell, cmd

I want to automatically check if some KB is installed on the machine.
Part of my python script:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['cmd', '/c wmic qfe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ftemp = open('mylog.txt','w') #just to check what is going wrong
ftemp.write(str(result.stdout))
ftemp.close()
if str(result.stdout).find('KB2999226')==-1:
    print('Nah, you don't have KB')
    sys.exit()
```

What I got in the shell while executing:

```
qfe" - Alias not found.
Nah, you don't have KB
```

mylog.txt:

```
b''
```

So, looks like some stupid problem with dashes or encodings. I've tried variety of commands, but nothing succeded.  (Yeah, "dism" causes another tons of errors).
Some advices?

Comment: Is the single quote in `'Nah, you don't have KB'` a typo?

Comment: But the command executes successfully from the cmd? So it's just the python script that causes the error?

Comment: also, is `wmic path win32_quickfixengineering get KB2999226` working?

Comment: 1) message was in Russian, without spec characters like in "don't". 2) command from cmd works with the same error. 3) ` result = subprocess.run(["cmd", '/c dism /Online /Get-Packages'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) `- returns some unreadable text in the result.stdout, while `dism /Online /Get-Packages` works perfectly from the cmd.

Comment: I don't like the single occurance of double-quotes in the error message you got. Is it for sure `qfe" - Alias not found.` and not `"qfe" - Alias not found.`??? In the latter case, what happens if you enter from the commandline `cmd /c wmic qfe`?

Comment: Yeah, single double-quotes! I have little expirience in windows cmd, so this strange problems with dashes pisses me off.

Comment: Maybe this is not really a Windows problem then. What happens if you supply a different command, for example `['cmd', '/c python --version']`. .... Nevertheless it would be still instructive to know what you get when you do the wmic from the command line, as I suggested.

Comment: ` ['cmd', '/c python --version'] ` works correctly. wmic returns: `Node - 201-19-1.   ERROR: Description = Invalid query `.

Comment: I take it that this is the expected result (which makes we wonder why you print only the stdout from within Python and not the stderr). As a next step, I would place the wmic command into a Batch file and run this Batch file instead.

Comment: One more idea: What is the effect, if you - just for the test - use `['cmd','/c','wmic','qfe','/?']`? Do you still get this error message, or do you you now see on stdout an explanation of the qfe command?

Comment: ['cmd','/c','wmic','qfe','/?'] returns "Invalid command". Batch file... yeah, but it is so confusing. It is already big project with a lot of strange parts that executes separately.... Program, which runs python-scipt, which runs cmd-script - looks terrible. But yeah, like a plan-b

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias

Answer (score 2):

Here is part of your problem:

```
print('Nah, you don't have KB')
```

should be

```
print("Nah, you don't have KB")
```

Comment: In fact, this message in Russian, without special characters like " ' ". So yeah, my bad - incorrect example

Comment: That makes sense and clears up some confusion. Otherwise you'd get a syntax error (which you didn't)

Answer (score 2):

Try separating all of the components into element in a list.

**Replace:**

```
result = subprocess.run(['cmd', '/c wmic qfe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**with**

```
result = subprocess.run(['cmd', '/c', 'wmic', 'qfe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Exactly the same output