# Run a (detached) QProcess using linux aliases and get result

Tags: python, linux, bash, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a "runner" using [QProcess.startDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1), but I'm having issues using Linux's aliases.
So far I've been able to run an alias using this code (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25099813)):

```
QtCore.QProcess.startDetached('/bin/bash', ['-i', '-c', 'somealias'])
```

The issue is that, since the actual "program" that is going to run is *bash*, it always returns `True`, even if the alias doesn't exists, meaning that the process "believes" that it has started, even if it actually hasn't, because `bash` was successfully run even if its alias hasn't been "found".

Obviously, this is not going to be a cross-platform program, and I know I could try and parse the current environment from the output of `aliases` (but, since aliases might include bash commands, that could be a problem).
Anyway I wander if there's another way to run a detached QProcess using Linux aliases, and eventually get the `False` returned value if the alias doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) points out:

> #### bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList
> &arguments, const QString &workingDirectory = QString(), qint64 *pid =
> nullptr)
>
> This function overloads startDetached().
>
> **Starts the program program with the arguments arguments in a new
> process, and detaches from it. Returns true on success; otherwise
> returns false.** If the calling process exits, the detached process will
> continue to run unaffected.
>
> Argument handling is identical to the respective start() overload.
>
> The process will be started in the directory workingDirectory. If
> workingDirectory is empty, the working directory is inherited from the
> calling process.
>
> If the function is successful then *pid is set to the process
> identifier of the started process.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In other words, returns a boolean that indicates if the command was started, it does not analyze if in the execution of the program your command was broken so it is not optimal for your requirement.

In this case, the solution is to use the finished signal that returns the execution status:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    command = "foo"

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    process = QtCore.QProcess()

    def on_finished(exitCode, exitStatus):
        print(exitCode == 0)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

    process.finished.connect(on_finished)
    process.start("/bin/bash", ["-i", "-c", command])
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output

```
False
```

---

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore


def check_alias(command):
    val = False
    process = QtCore.QProcess()
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()

    def on_finished(exitCode, exitStatus):
        nonlocal val
        val = exitCode == 0
        loop.quit()

    process.finished.connect(on_finished)
    process.start("/bin/bash", ["-i", "-c", command])
    loop.exec_()
    return val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
   
    for command in ("foo", "ls"):
        print(f"{command}: {check_alias(command)}")
```

Output:

```
foo: False
ls: True
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore


def check_alias(command):
    val = False
    process = QtCore.QProcess()
    process.start("/bin/bash", ["-i", "-c", command])
    process.waitForFinished(-1)
    return process.exitCode() == 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    for command in ("foo", "ls"):
        print(f"{command}: {check_alias(command)}")
```

Output:

```
foo: False
ls: True
```

Comment: But, according to this, I won't be able to run a detached process (as in "run the process independently"): I need to run it and ensure that it's actually *started*, but after that I should also be able to use or even close my application independently. As far as I can understand, I'm afraid that what I'm looking for is not actually possible, at least using Qt only. (sorry for the late reply, btw, I didn't have time to test it as I needed)

Comment: @musicamante 1) It seems that you don't understand the flow of how QProcess::startDetached works with bash, when you start bash QProcess is notified of it and QProcess will no longer listen, but a moment later bash just starts executing its own command that may or may not fail and no longer notify QProcess. 2) And as you point out, it is not possible to monitor the life cycle of an application with QProcess::startDetached. 3) The solution for your case is to monitor using QProcess as my example shows.