# VS Code Remote does not pick up .bash_profile in ssh

Tags: python, bash, ssh, hpc, vscode-remote

I was using Python to run a bash script after I wrote several commands into it. 
These commands are mostly Python scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
./xmlchange JOB_WALLCLOCK_TIME=30:00:00
./xmlchange NTASKS=40
./case.setup
cp ../something ./something  
./xmlchange something
./case.build
./case.submit
```

I call the bash script from Python like this:

```
os.chmod("./run.sh", stat.S_IRWXU )
subprocess.call("./run.sh")
```

The last command, however, (./case.submit), always behaves differently. This command is used to submit a SLURM job to a queue. If I ran this bash script directly from Python, the job always crashed almost immediately due to memory issue.

But if I ran the last command from my terminal, the job ran ok.

Therefore, I am questioning whether the environment is the same in the VS Code session with the default login session. Because at least the "Terminal" tab interface is not the same, it does not load the .bash_profile.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: .bash_profile is only executed for login shells like ssh whereas a terminal is interactive and non-login and executes .bashrc. [Python subprocess.call a bash alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias) might help you.

Comment: It appears that I can: For example, to enable running bash as a login shell (which runs .bash_profile), pass in the -l argument (with double quotes): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 4):

Remove your `/home/username/.vscode-server`

```
cd ~/
rm -rf .vscode-server
```

and restart vscode. Then you can use the `.bash_profile` that you made.

Comment: this trick works!

Comment: yeah had .profile on target computer one day just be completely ignored when ssh'ing through vscode. this worked and then when connecting again with vscode i saw it remake that .vscode-server again fresh but this time paths i set in .profile seem to be working. and I was able connect few times with paths working. Then I tried ctrl-d to log out of ssh and when reconnecting the ignored .profile issue came back so have to erase .vscode-server folder each time I log out it seems.