# Python: subprocess.call('nvm ls', shell=True) giving this error /bin/sh: nvm: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, nvm

```
def runLinter2( ):
subprocess.call('nvm ls', shell=True)
return
```

When i run this python script, it gives error "error /bin/sh: nvm: command not found"
but when i tun simply this `nvm ls` in the terminal, it works.

To run python script, i am using this command `python3 test.py`

Could i get help on it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here [Python subprocess.call a bash alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias)

You should be able to call

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', command])
```

so that you can access the alias defined in `~/.bashrc`