# Unable to open sublime from subprocess module?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I am running the following script on my Mac:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "sublime driver.py"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
p.wait()
```

I am in the directory with the file `driver.py`. So, if I was on my terminal and did `sublime driver.py` it would work just fine. However I am getting this error when I run this program:
`/bin/sh: sublime: command not found`.

Why is that? I am assuming because the command "sublime" is an alias in .bash_profile, defined as

`alias sublime="open -a /Applications/SublimeText.app"`

How can I run an alias through the subprocess module in python 3?

Comment: Try `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), shell=True)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, thanks for your response. I am getting this error now: ```driver.py: sublime: command not found```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right,

try following:-

```
import subprocess

cmd = "open -a /Applications/SublimeText.app driver.py"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
p.wait()
```

If you still want to run the command using alias check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060863/python-subprocess-call-a-bash-alias)